# Mirroring a picture

Tags: c++

I've tried to mirror my picture but I've only been able to rotate the picture 180 degrees. Here's the code I have:

```
for (int s = width; s > 0; s--){
    for (int g = height; g > 0; g--)
      fout << picture[s-1][g-1] << ' ';
  }
```

What am I doing wrong to mirror it?

Comment: You should only mirror the x coordinate and leave the y coordinate unchanged.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and expected output? Also, see how to write an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will help you get a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are mirroring the "image" along both axis at the same time, which is the same as rotating in 180 degrees. You have to reverse the order of *one* of your loops, not both at the same time.

So, depending on what "mirroring" means for you, either start `s` from 0 and go up, or do that for `g`, not both.

This is probably what you mean by "mirroring":

```
for (int s = width; s > 0; s--){
    for (int g = 1; g <= height; g++)
        fout << picture[s-1][g-1] << ' ';
    }
```